# Exclude row in ROW_NUMBER() with case

Tags: sql, sqlite

`sales_data` table:

```
create table sales_data
(
    store int,
    sales_year int,
    sales_total float
);
```

`sales_data` data:

| store | sales_year | sales_total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020 | 100 |
| 1 | 2021 | 120 |
| 1 | 2022 | 60 |

Problematic query on `sales_data`:

```
select 
    sales_year,
    sales_total,
    case 
        when sales_year <> 2022
            then row_number() over (partition by store order by sales_total) 
    end as rn
from 
    sales_data
order by 
    sales_year
```

Result (unwanted):

| sales_year | sales_total | rn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 100 | 2 |
| 2021 | 120 | 3 |
| 2022 | 60 |  |

Why does `row_number()` start from 2? How I can make it start from 1?
I want to keep all sales year, so I cannot exclude in where.

Desired result:

| sales_year | sales_total | rn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 100 | 1 |
| 2021 | 120 | 2 |
| 2022 | 60 |  |

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() always starts from 1, but you've replaced certain rowNumbers with NULL ***after*** they've been calculated. You can't exclude a row from ROW_NUMBER(), but you can use PARTITION BY to put some rows in a different ROW_NUMBER() sequence, and then use CASE expressions to replace the whole partition with NULL results.

Comment: Yes I understand this, check @lemon answer, for a way to do it

Comment: If you understand that, why ask the question. I was responding to your question, not to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ROW_NUMBER` ranking starts from 2 instead of 1 because it works on all your data. Not displaying it doesn't mean value 1 doesn't get assigned to 2022.

In order to solve this problem, you can twist your `ROW_NUMBER` ordering just a bit by adding partitioning on the boolean value `sales_year = 2022` as follows:

```
select 
    sales_year,
    sales_total,
    case 
        when sales_year <> 2022
        then ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY store, sales_year=2022 ORDER BY sales_total) 
    end as rn
from sales_data
order by sales_year
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a7RPKKLkqDVrJ6qAJ6fLEo/0).

Comment: This seems to work, but what is the exact meaning? From https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/window-defn.html it shows that partition by accepts expression. Why not: store, sales_year<>2022?

Comment: The idea is to generate a boolean (0/1) value with the expression `sales_year = 2022`: these new two partitions will make the counter of `ROW_NUMBER` restart back from 1 (both 2022 and 2020 will be assigned rn=1 because they are both the first of their ranking partition, on the other hand 2021 is the second value of partition (sales_year=2022) = 0 (false), ordered by sales_total).

Comment: Yes, so this is not filter in 2022, but partitioning specifying the exact value. Thanks

Comment: @paul Try it with = and again with <>. They'll give the same result. Imagine you're partitioning by a new column called "rows_to_keep" all the rows with TRUE will be in a different partition from the rows with FALSE. Now imagine you partition by a new column called "rows_to_ignore", all the rows with FALSE will be in a different partition from the rows with TRUE. All you're doing is creating two partitions per store, and getting two ROW_NUMBER sequences per store. Then, you use CASE expressions to ignore one of those sequences.

Comment: @MatBailie yes you can use more complicated expressions like: "store, sales_year in (2020, 2022)" in partition by, and create the group combination. cool.

Answer (score 2):

For the hell of it, here's another (though I would say worse) way to do it.

Instead of creating two partitions per store, force some rows to be ordered ***last*** within the partition.

That way, when your CASE expression 'ignores' some of the results, they're always the last rows and so don't leave 'holes' in the sequences.

```
select 
    sales_year,
    sales_total,
    case 
        when sales_year <> 2022
            then row_number() over (partition by store order by sales_year = 2022, sales_total) 
    end as rn
from 
    sales_data
order by 
    sales_year
```

***Note:*** False comes before True, like 0 comes before 1. So, the ORDER BY puts the rows that are 2022 after all the other rows.

Partitioning is cheaper than sorting, so don't do this. It's just an example to help clarify that "excluding rows" from rowNumber isn't an option, but that if you control where a row is included, you can subsequently ignore the result safely.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/24ZxTg91AWpkJwZqZa9Kxd/0